# Term for two objects with the same properties or keys

Tags: object-oriented

I believe I learned (and later forgot) a term for two (or more) objects/dictionaries, with the same property schema. Googling has not helped. For example, these objects are TERMs because they have all the same properties.

Comment: Could homogenous be the word you're looking for?